# Generate different possible counterexamples in NuSMV

Tags: logic, formal-verification, temporal, formal-methods, nusmv

I wish to know if there is a way to generate different possible counterexamples for a given LTL formula in NuSMV. If we need to generate counterexample for an LTL formula, it generates one for us. But the one generated by NuSMV may not be the most exciting or insightful because there may be other counterexamples to the same LTL formula.

Can you suggest some general ways to ask NuSMV to produce some different counterexample than the one it produced?

One way would be to modify the LTL formula itself so that the counterexample produced by NuSMV in one-shot is interesting for us. But I believe that is too much rigging of the system to get the result that you want.

Plus you need to know beforehand the interesting result. But if I already know the interesting counterexample, why would I ask NuSMV to reconfirm it to me? And why then go through the hassle of designing an LTL expression which will give the desired counterexample? I want NuSMV to generate other interesting counterexamples which I had not thought of thereby adding value.

And if it is not possible in NuSMV can you suggest any other LTL model checker where this is possible?